# date ticks does not align with line graph points

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js

I have a graph like this so far.
[line chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcWiE.png)

***Issue:*** 1. Date ticks are slightly off to the right and 2. Does not start from the origin.

***Goal:*** I want to draw ticks that aligns with circle

***stack:*** typescript, angular2, d3 v4

I'm not sure whether xScale or xAxis is off.

---

Here, I have two arrays.

````
```data1 = [
  {date: new Date('2017-04-23'), value: 8000},
  {date: new Date('2017-04-24'), value: 6000},
  {date: new Date('2017-04-25'), value: 14000},
  {date: new Date('2017-04-26'), value: 12000},
  {date: new Date('2017-04-27'), value: 18000},
  {date: new Date('2017-04-28'), value: 14300},
  {date: new Date('2017-04-29'), value: 17000}
];
data2 = [
  {date: new Date('2017-04-23'), value: 7500},
  {date: new Date('2017-04-24'), value: 5300},
  {date: new Date('2017-04-25'), value: 13000},
  {date: new Date('2017-04-26'), value: 10000}
];```
````

And this is my code below:

```js
export class DashboardProgressGraphComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('chart') private chartContainer: ElementRef;
  @Input() private data1: Array<any>;
  @Input() private data2: Array<any>;
  private margin: any = { top: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50, right: 20};
  private chart: any;
  private width: number;
  private height: number;
  private xScale: any;
  private yScale: any;
  private colors: any;
  private xAxis: any;
  private yAxis: any;
  private line1: d3Shape.Line<[number, number]>;
  private line2: d3Shape.Line<[number, number]>;
  private svg: any;
  
  ngOnInit() {
    this.createChart();
  }
  
  createChart() {
    const element = this.chartContainer.nativeElement;
    this.width = element.offsetWidth - this.margin.left - this.margin.right;
    this.height = element.offsetHeight - this.margin.top - this.margin.bottom;
    this.svg = d3.select(element).append('svg')
      .attr('width', element.offsetWidth)
      .attr('height', element.offsetHeight);

    // chart plot area
    this.chart = this.svg.append('g')
      .attr('transform', `translate(${this.margin.left}, ${this.margin.top})`);

    // set the ranges
    this.xScale = d3.scaleTime().range([0, this.width]).domain(d3.extent(this.data1, d => d.date));
    this.yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([this.height, 0]).domain([0, d3.max(this.data1, d => d.value )]);

    // define the line
    this.line1 = d3.line()
      .x( (d: any) => this.xScale(d.date) )
      .y( (d: any) => this.yScale(d.value) );
    this.line2 = d3.line()
      .x( (d: any) => this.xScale(d.date) )
      .y( (d: any) => this.yScale(d.value) );

    // draw x & y axis
    this.xAxis = this.svg.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'axis x-axis')
      .attr('transform', `translate(${this.margin.left}, ${this.margin.top + this.height})`)
      .call(d3.axisBottom(this.xScale).ticks(d3.timeDay.every(1)));
    this.yAxis = this.svg.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'axis y-axis')
      .attr('transform', `translate(${this.margin.left}, ${this.margin.top})`)
      .call(d3.axisLeft(this.yScale));
      
    // draw line1
    this.chart.append('path')
      .datum(this.data1)
      .attr('class', 'line1')
      .attr('d', this.line1);

    // draw line2
    this.chart.append('path')
      .datum(this.data2)
      .attr('class', 'line2')
      .attr('d', this.line2);

    // draw dots on line1
    this.svg.selectAll('dot')
      .data(this.data1)
      .enter().append('circle')
      .attr('class', 'dot1')
      .attr('r', 5)
      .attr('cx', d => this.xScale(d.date) + 50)
      .attr('cy', d => this.yScale(d.value) + 20)
      .on('mouseover', d => this.tooltip.style('opacity', 1))
      .on('mouseout', d => this.tooltip.style('opacity', 0));

    // draw dots on line2
    this.svg.selectAll('dot')
      .data(this.data2)
      .enter().append('circle')
      .attr('class', 'dot2')
      .attr('r', 5)
      .attr('cx', d => this.xScale(d.date) + 50)
      .attr('cy', d => this.yScale(d.value) + 20)
      .on('mouseover', d => this.tooltip.style('opacity', 1))
      .on('mouseout', d => this.tooltip.style('opacity', 0));
  }
}
```

sorry for confusion with typescript and class function but you only have to look at the code inside createChart() function.
Problem is occurred where I set xScale or set xAxis.
This can be found under commented line *// set the ranges* and *// draw x & y axis*

---

**EDIT:**
I added .nice(d3.timeDay) to the xScale as @TheBiro suggested.
and added .tickSize(-this.height) to show how the the graph is off from the ticks.

[editted line chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYGTw.png)

as you can see, the line path and circle are still off from the ticks.
It did not solve the problem..

Comment: Your snippet gives an error

Comment: i just threw in my angular2 code there but if you look at the chart image, it's very straightforward what it's doing. @TheBiro

Comment: But it gets hard to test in my computer, since I don't really know whats the problem exactaly. I'd suggest yu to add `.nice(d3.timeWeek)` in `xScale` like this: `xScale=d3.scaleTime().nice(d3.timeWeek)....`

Comment: I tried chaining .nice(d3.timeDay) instead to the xScale. it helped little bit by adjusting ticks but the graph is still off. I'm working on rewriting in pure JS (without angular and ts). I will update the snippet. @TheBiro

Comment: Maybe different timezone? What are the values of the parsed dates?